# Finding a slope of a given point in a data set using python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data in a txt file that is comprised of two columns that I can retrieve and put as two arrays using numpy (X,Y).

```
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:\\python')
xvalue = np.loadtxt("test.txt", delimiter= " ")[:, 0]
yvalue = np.loadtxt("test.txt", delimiter= " ")[:, 1]

x = np.array(xvalue)
y = np.array(yvalue)
zip(x,y)
```

Assuming that the data is something like the green line in this picture:
[image: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/_images/numpy-polyfit-1.png] (sorry I couldn't post it directly)

How can I obtain the slope in a given data-point?
For example, what if I wanted to know the slope when x = 1 or when the y = 0 (in which my case only happens once), is there a viable method?

Comment: There are many methods. You can evaluate the derivative function at that point if it's analytically known, or more likely you will take a forward, backward, or center difference between the closest points. [You can check out wikipedia for how to do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#:~:text=A%20finite%20difference%20is%20a,one%20gets%20a%20difference%20quotient.&text=The%20formal%20calculus%20of%20finite,to%20the%20calculus%20of%20infinitesimals.)

Comment: Taking a difference between the closest points is not viable as I have several archives of this data and I want to automatize this. Also, the points of interest sometimes differ between different archives, lets say that I'm interested in X = 0 , in this case in one file could be Y = 42  and in another Y= 32. I just wanted to know if there was a function that could retrieve the data point near a given data and find a slope of this point.

Comment: You just need to know the index of the number your interested (`i`) in for a difference method. Then you use the previous(`i - 1`) and/or next (`i + 1`) index to calculate a difference. If you want an entire array of the differences you could always [use this numpy function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) for forward differences. Then you just need to divide by the step size.